# Why am I getting contradictory errors?

Tags: errors

I'm trying to write the two lines:

```
$framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}$
${1 - \sqrt{50}} = \framebox{1 - 5\sqrt{2}}$
```

I use frameboxes earlier and later in the document, but for some reason I get the following four errors:

```
Missing $ inserted. $\framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}
Extra }, or forgotten $. $\framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}
Missing $ inserted. $\framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}
Missing } inserted. $\framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Obviously you meant `$\framebox{-4+2\sqrt{5}}$` in the first line

Answer (score 3):

The `\framebox{}` command puts its argument in text mode, you see? So you then get errors, because you have math commands in text mode. TeX sees your math commands and knows they should be in math mode, which is why you get this `Missing $ inserted` message. And then of course the closing `$` is missing, which is why you get this `forgotten $` message.

Anyway, the obvious solution is to enter math mode within the `\framebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\framebox{$-4+2\sqrt{5}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, [as egreg says in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341401/why-am-i-getting-contradictory-errors/341404?noredirect=1#comment837718_341404), you can just use the `\boxed{}` command:

```
$\boxed{-4+2\sqrt{5}}$
```

This approach is probably to be recommended because if you want to use display math mode to display the equation (`\[ ... \]`) - which you probably will, if you're putting a box around it - it's a lot cleaner to use `\boxed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Compare
\[
  \framebox{$\displaystyle \int x^{2} \, dx$}
\]
With
\[
  \boxed{\int x^{2} \, dx}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or use `$\boxed{-4+2\sqrt{5}}$`

Comment: @egreg Good point. Arguably a better approach really, especially if you want to display the equation (which you probably do if you're putting a box around it ...) but since the OP asked about `\framebox{}` I thought I'd focus on that, and explaining where the error comes from (math commands in text mode)

Comment: I understand it, but you can also suggest the better method.

Comment: @egreg I was gonna leave it to you, but, if you wish :)